# Как правильно хранить .gitignore и readme.md в проекте залитым на GitHub?

Tags: reactjs, git, github, gitignore

В корне моего проекта у меня лежат 3 папки: .git, client и server. В папке client, в свою очередь, лежит React приложение, в том числе и .gitignore с readme.md, то есть эти 2 вспомогательных файла лежат НЕ в корне проекта и .gitignore, насколько я понимаю, игнорируется гитхабом. Я это понял потому, что в .gitignore добавлена исключение /node_modules, но эта папка все равно залилась на гитхаб. Это большая папка, и каждый раз загружать ее на гитхаб очень долго и бесмысленно, ведь каждый сможет загрузить все зависимости командой npm install. Я подумал просто закинуть этот файл в корень проекта, но ведь тогда придется поменять пути всех прописанных автоматически файлов и папок (приписать в начале "/client"), и я боюсь что-то испортить. Что вы думаете по этому поводу? На скриншоте содержимое .gitignore файла.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вы уже залили node_modules, то применять .gitignore слишком поздно, нужно сперва удалить залитое

Comment: Да гитхаб вроде не должен игнорировать вложенные .git* файлы,

Comment: Github-у вообще неважно что в .gitignore. Это важно только при добавлении *новых* файлов в репозиторий. В остальном это стандартный вопрос «почему gitignore не работает»

Comment: А теперь главный вопрос: гитхаб будет игнорировать только если файл .gitignore лежит в корне проекта или необязательно и у меня сейчас все правильно?

Comment: Повторюсь ещё раз, GitHub-у вообще наплевать на `.gitignore`. Для него это просто файлик. `git` смотрит на все `.gitignore`-файлы (включая ваш в подпапке) просто область действия каждого такого файла это папка в которой он лежит и её потомки. Т.е. ваш файл действует только на папку `client/` и ниже